# Sentence with date and time

Tags: sentence

Given below are two set of questions. Could you please let me know which among the two is right?

Set #1:
The books shall be delivered tomorrow noon.
The books shall be delivered noon tomorrow.

Set #2:
The books shall be arriving on this Wednesday, 8 A.M.
The books shall be arriving at 8 A.M. on this Wednesday.

Kind regards,
Kumar

Comment: I'm guessing that "shall" is used in this way in Indian English: I don't think anybody anywhere else in the Anglosphere would say these. This makes it hard to answer the rest of your question, because I suspect that this would also have a different answer in Indian English from other Englishes. For example, I wouldn't say "on this Wednesday", I would say either "on Wednesday" or "this Wednesday". (I realise that that is not what you were asking about, but if I tell you that I would say "on Wednesday at 8 am " or "at 8 am on Wednesday", I'm not sure that my British English answer helps you).

Comment: Following the rule that a day/ date has a preposition 'on', many Indians do it. Of course, it kills the beauty of sentence. 2) Re: the other parts of the questions, the usual order is day/date-time-venue.  The books will be arriving this Wednesday (at) 8 am.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering the question. It really helps.

Comment: @ColinFine The use of *shall* here seems perfectly normal to me, albeit less common than other variations (*will be*, *are going to be*). I wouldn't call it a matter of Indian English at all. It's at least part of Canadian English. Similarly, *on this Wednesday* is also fine—although also less common, and reminiscent of old-fashioned English. But, again, i would not put it under an Indian regionalism.

Comment: @JasonBassford. Maybe.The GloWbE corpus shows just five hits for "shall be arriving", all with 1st person subjects.  The iWeb corpus has 12 hits, of which 9 are not 1st person. But of these 9, 3 are from a 19thC book, 1 from an official announcement in some fan fic, 2 are from posts on forums for immigration questions into the US and UK, and one an announcement from an Italian cycling magazine. Two are left, that actually seem to be current utterance from native English a speaker: they are from an announcement of releases from a games manufacturer. They read oddly to me.